# Change a graphics Function

Tags: pgfplots

I have this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
xlabel= $Interes$, ylabel=$Power$,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
ultra thick,
y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{sqrt(#1)}},
y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{pow(#1,2)}}
] 
\addplot coordinates {
    (0,0)
    (1,5)
    (0.4,0.75)

};
\draw[red, dashed] (axis cs:0.5, 0)--(axis cs:0.5, 5);
\draw[red, dashed] (axis cs:0, 1.3)--(axis cs:1, 1.3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want remove the automatic line that connecting points.
I want remove the 'y' and 'x' coordinates

I want to write up of the points

I want this:
[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Try **\addplot[only marks...**

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand how to remove the coordinates and how I write up of the points :( Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you need the `only marks` key/option in the `addplot` command..

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
xlabel= $Interes$, ylabel=$Power$,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
ultra thick,
y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{sqrt(#1)}},
y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{pow(#1,2)}}
] 
\addplot[only marks,blue] coordinates { % <-- the magic happens here
    (0,0)
    (1,5)
    (0.4,0.75)

};
\draw[red, dashed] (axis cs:0.5, 0)--(axis cs:0.5, 5);
\draw[red, dashed] (axis cs:0, 1.3)--(axis cs:1, 1.3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `xticklabels={},yticklabels={}` I think, and `nodes near coords`.

Comment: Thanks! But I do not understand how to remove the coordinates and how I write up of the points :( Thanks

Comment: @Solid Read the hint from Torbjørn T. Do you know the pgfplots manual?

Comment: No sorry. I am a normal user Latex. I don´t know make a dificults things.

Comment: I have finished my work. Only I have to remove the : 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6... Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @solid see the first comment, there you have the solution. And reading the manual is for normal users.